# addClass() not work after mouseover event

Tags: jquery

Hi all when I add class using `jquery` added class not work

```
$('.t_wrapper').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('t_active');
});
$('.t_wrapper').mouseout(function () {
    $('.t_wrapper').removeClass('t_active');
});
```

// `'.t_active'` not recognize like parent tag sorry for my English :(

```
var tag = $('.t_active .tables li:nth-child(' + n + ')');
```

Comment: Maybe you should provide a little bit more of your code, posting on JSFiddle or something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1:

```
 $('.t_wrapper').mouseenter(function () {
      $(this).addClass('t_active');
 });
 $('.t_wrapper').mouseleave(function () {
      $(this).removeClass('t_active');
 });
```

Option 2

```
 $('.t_wrapper').mouseover(function () {
      $('.t_wrapper').addClass('t_active');
 });
 $('.t_wrapper').mouseout(function () {
      $('.t_wrapper').removeClass('t_active');
 });
```

Each time your mouse enters or leaves a child element, mouseover is triggered, but not mouseenter.
For this reason dont use $(this) in mouseover or mouseout, they are not the same target.

Comment: only 3 minutes left :) and your answer will be correct answer :)